# Elixir receive message: how do I run multiple statements?

Tags: elixir

How do I code multiple statements in a single Elixir receive do pattern match?

This works:

```
def pong sender do
  receive do
    x -> IO.puts("hello"); IO.puts("there"); send(sender, x)
  end
end
```

But what if I cannot put them all on the same line? Can they be bracketed using a do end clause? Because this does not work:

```
def pong sender do
  receive do
    x -> do
           IO.puts("hello")
           IO.puts("there")
           send(sender, x)
         end
  end
end
```

Comment: You can remove the `do` and `end` from your second example and it will work. Like you can do with case http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/case-cond-and-if.html#case

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you can just omit `do/end`:

```
def pong sender do
  receive do
    x ->
      IO.puts("hello")
      IO.puts("there")
      send(sender, x)
  end
end
```